# Difference between entry_points/console_scripts and scripts in setup.py?

Tags: python, package, setup.py

There are basically two ways to install Python console scripts to my path by `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = package.module:func',
        ],
    }
)
```

and

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts = [
        'scripts/myscript.sh'
    ]
)
```

What are the differences? I see the first approach allows me to choose nice, specific name for my script, but are there any other differences? Different original purposes, compatibility (setuptools, distutils, ...?), usage, ...? I am quite confused and a nice elaborated reply could help me (and probably also others) to properly understand all this.

**Update:** Since I asked the question [PyPA](https://www.pypa.io/) published [these cool docs on the topic](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts).

Comment: The [update] link broken. I believe https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#scripts is the replacement(?)

Comment: The link in your update has updated again: https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/?highlight=scripts#scripts

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The docs for the (awesome) Click package [suggest a few reasons](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/setuptools/) to use entry points instead of scripts, including

1. cross-platform compatibility and
2. avoiding having the interpreter assign `__name__` to `__main__`, which could cause code to be imported twice (if another module imports your script)

Click is a nice way to implement functions for use as `entry_points`, btw.

Comment: This is the right answer. Basically there where a lot of problems with the old distutils. A bunch of really smart people created setuptools to supersede it. They collaborated and came up with the entry_points/console_scripts mechanism to be the standard for executable distribution so you don't have to think about the problems with all the other options. Don't be a hero. Use what you've been given.

Comment: I would like to add that since I asked the question, these awesome docs emerged: http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/#scripts

Comment: Unfortunately @HonzaJavorek - those "awesome docs" are now a 404 / non-existent :/

Comment: They exist, only the structure has changed. New link: https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/search/?q=scripts

Comment: Can you further explain 'imported twice'? I was under the impression that "if __name__ == '__main__':'" is used to solve this problem?

Comment: @tribbloid:  Explanation:  https://ncoghlan-devs-python-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#executing-the-main-module-twice

Comment: `entry_points.console_scripts` is now officially recommended over `scripts` https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/?highlight=scripts#scripts

Answer (score 16):

One key difference between these two ways of creating command line executables is that with the `setuptools` approach (your first example), you have to call a function inside of the script -- in your case this is the `func` inside of your `module`.  However, in the `distutils` approach (your second example) you call the script directly (which allows being listed with or without an extension).

Comment: I think this answer misses the main point. The entry_point approach is the new way that we should all be using. Anytime there is a setuptools alternative to a distutils functionality, it's for a very good reason.

Comment: Alternatively, it would seem that `scripts` is the only way to include a custom script, for example a WSGI script instead of a command line script. `entry_points` will always generate a command line executable of some kind. (Whether that's a *good* idea, I'm not sure, but it is an observation.)

Answer (score 10):

The setup tools entry point approach (#1) also has [the benefit](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) that on windows an .exe will be created that can be double clicked and invoked like a regular windows program. This is in addition to having a script placed in the bin path on posix-like systems.

Answer (score 5):

One more difference is that when using console_scripts, my module's `__init__` file was run. When just using scripts, the module `__init__` was not run, only the script was run.