# Pros and cons of 'script' vs. 'entry_point' in Python command line scripts

Tags: python, scripting, setuptools, setup.py

Python's [setuptool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) has two ways of adding command line scripts to a Python package: `script` and `entry_point`.

[This tutorial](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html) outlines these ways:

### `scripts`

Add a Python script (`funniest-joke`) to the package tree, and add its path to `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['bin/funniest-joke'],
    ...
)
```

### Entry point:

Add a Python script (`funniest-joke`) to the package tree. Add a `main()` function to it, and add `command_line.py` submodule which runs funniest's `main()`:

#### `command_line.py`:

```
import funniest

def main():
    print funniest.joke()
```

#### `setup.py`

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['funniest-joke=funniest.command_line:main'],
    }
    ...
)
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between entry\_points/console\_scripts and scripts in setup.py?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787036/difference-between-entry-points-console-scripts-and-scripts-in-setup-py)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically scripts is the old way which requires you to have a stand-alone, executable script file and the entry-points method lets you define which functions you want to run when a command is given.  This way you can have several functions in the same file/module and then have 'entry points' which will be called when the user types in one of the `console_scripts` commands.

> Although setup() supports a scripts keyword for pointing to pre-made scripts to install, the recommended approach to achieve cross-platform compatibility is to use console_scripts entry points (see below).

From https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#scripts ([old source](https://github.com/pypa/python-packaging-user-guide/blob/master/source/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools.rst#scripts))