# Imports inside package now that __init__.py is optional

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I'm building a package that contains scripts to be run. They import modules contained in a subfolder directly under the script. Now that [`__init__` is not required after Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991978/7089239), what's the correct file structure and `import` statement to have? I'd like to not have to specify the import from the topmost folder down, only as a relative path, here `sub/module`.

This is the current state of the file structure:

```
Root\
    src\
        sub\
            module.py
        script.py
        parent_module.py
    setup.py

# Inside script.py
import sub.module      # Doesn't work
from sub import module # Doesn't work
import src.sub.module  # Does work!

import .sub.module     # Doesn't work
import .parent_module  # Does work!
```

I imagine I need to have *some* `__init__` file, but what and where would that be? Any help is greatly appreciated, I don't know much about packaging.

Also, I'm certainly open to suggestions to changing the structure, if that makes things easier.

Comment: What is your Python version? (run `python -V` to check)

Comment: @kristaps Python 3.6.5, so very much after 3.3.x

Comment: Note that not having ``__init__.py`` still makes a difference - it marks a namespace package. For a regular package, you should continue adding ``__init__.py`` as before.

Comment: How are you running script.py? I am getting completely different results.

Comment: @itsadok That is a **valuable** comment. Never rely on IDE errors before executing an interpreted language. PyCharm gives an error, program executes just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing `__init__.py` are not the problem - you are using outdated relative imports.

```
import sub.module         # implicit relative import - py2 only
from . import sub.module  # explicit relative import
```

Note that a `.` import always requires the `from .<where> import <name>` form. It would not produce a valid name otherwise. The following should work, assuming your run `script.py` via `python3 -m src.script` - an IDE will likely do the same.

```
from . import sub.module
from .sub import module
from .sub.module import *
from . import parent_module
```

If you are running as plain `python3 script.py` or `python3 -m script`, you cannot use relative imports. Only absolute imports will work in this case.

```
import sub.module
from sub import module
from sub.module import *
import parent_module
```

---

While you do not need `__init__.py` files, it is a good idea to add them if your package is not a namespace. Otherwise, other similarly constructed packages of the same name may be inserted into yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It seems the absolute imports are the way to go. Now that I've been [struggling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375324/referencing-custom-python-modules-and-data-files) with this for a while, may I ask a few direct questions that may not be in the best style of these forums? I hope you'll humor me. Do these absolute imports work if this is installed with setuptools and executed as a cmd script? If not, how would you, however briefly explained, install and execute scripts that need custom modules to run to a different environment?

Comment: PyCharm already is a *bit* different with its script execution, so I'd like to be sure.

Comment: @Felix Installing with setuptools is fine - you can then use absolute imports in any case. I suggest using the console_scripts entry point, though, since it allows relative imports for both development and deployment. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18787036/5349916 and http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point for reference.