# How does python library handle internal imports?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following directory

```
myProject
    myCode.py
    __init__.py
myProject2
    __init__.py
    myProject2Inner
         myCode.py
         __init__.py

myLibrary
    __init__.py
    myPackage1
        __init__.py
        myPackage1Code.py
    myPackage2
        __init__.py
        myPackage2Code.py
```

If `myCode.py` is dependent on `myPackage1Code.py` and `myPackage1Code.py` is dependent on `myPackage2Code.py`

I am currently doing the following

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../myLibrary/myPackage2/'))
import myPackage2Code
```

in `myPackage1Code.py` to make the code run successfully. But this is obviously really bad since the library import path is entirely dependent on who is using it. For example if `myProject2Inner` requires `myPackage1` then the code above wouldn't work.

I would have to do

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../myLibrary/myPackage2/'))
import myPackage2Code
```

I think I am doing something really wrong here, can someone point me a direction of how to handle import path within a self containing library?

Comment: Wouldn't it help if you simply add the path to `myLibrary` to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct import and package structure now that \_\_init\_\_.py is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397669/correct-import-and-package-structure-now-that-init-py-is-optional)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `myLibrary`, `myPackage1` and `myPackage2` are packages. To import modules (or packages) from other packages, you must either use an absolute or relative path:

```
# in myPackage1Code.py
# absolute import
from myLibrary.myPackage2 import myPackage2Code
# relative import
from ..myPackage2 import myPackage2Code
```

This uniquely identifies the module you actually want, and tells Python where to find it. Note that `.` and `..`  are *not* file-system operations: they also work with dynamically composed namespace packages.

If you want to execute a script contained inside your package, you execute it as part of the package:

```
python2 -m myLibrary.myPackage1.myPackage1Code
```

---

Python2 also has *implicit* relative imports:

```
# in myLibrary/__init__.py
from myPackage2 import myPackage2Code
```

This form is generally discouraged, as it breaks if there is a global `myPackage2`. It also does not work with Python3.

---

Note that for packages to work, you have to use them as such! If you directly access part of a package (**don't do this at home!**)

```
 # directly run code module of a package in the shell
 python2 myLibrary/myPackage1/myPackage1Code.py


 # directly import module of a package
 sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../myLibrary/myPackage2/'))
 import myPackage2Code
```

then Python does not know that `myPackage2Code` belongs to `myLibrary.myPackage2`.
This has two notable effects:

- The `myPackage2Code` cannot use relative imports. Python considers it a top-level module, so imports cannot go "up" in the package hierarchy.
- If another module imports it with its full path, this creates two separate modules `myPackage2Code` and `myLibrary.myPackage2.myPackage2Code`. Since these contain separate objects, they for example fail `isinstance` checks of `except` clauses.