# Importing from folders at the same hierarchy level

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking around this site for how I can import a class stored in a folder at the same hierarchy level. What I found is that using `..` should bring me up one folder. Or at least, that is how I read it as that assumption seems to be wrong.

```
src/
    folderStrucutre1/
        __init__.py
        fileToImport.py <- contains A
    folderStrucutre2/
        someFile.py
        __init__.py
abc.py
```

Having above folder structure in which `fileToImport.py` contains a class named `A`. How would I import `A` into someFile.py?

Comment: Maybe `import ..folderStructure1.fileToImport`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does python library handle internal imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863776/how-does-python-library-handle-internal-imports/53864451#53864451)

Answer (score 1):

Due to how packages work in python, you need to move `src` and `abc.py` into a subfolder, and provide an `__init__.py` for it.

The directory structure should look like this after the changes:

```
package-name/
    package-name/
        folderStructure1/
            __init__.py
            fileToImport.py <- contains A
        folderStructure2/
            __init__.py
            someFile.py
    __init__.py
    abc.py
```

Then, in `someFile.py` you can import `A` using a relative import from the parent package:

```
from ..folderStructure1.fileToImport import A
```

Lastly, you should open the topmost folder (parent to abc.py) for IDE `intellisense` to work

Comment: This gives: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package, in Intellisense.

Comment: did you add a `__init__.py` file alongside `abc.py`? I realized I forgot to add it in the example structure, so if you didn't add one because of that it's my bad :P I edited the diagram to include `__init__.py` for future reference

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to create the absolute path to your `src` folder without hard-coding it in your script to make it **portable**.

Add this code in your `someFile.py` file.

```
import os
src_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Now, let's add your `folderStructure1` directory to the **Python Search Path**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(src_path + '/folderStructure1')
```

Now you can use the following:

```
from fileToImport import Class
object = Class()
```

Comment: The point is that ``someFile`` (and every other module next to or below it) is visible to ``someFile`` in the first place.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't understand what's wrong with that, can you elaborate?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Also, would appending the specific directory in the parent class to `PATH` solve this issue? I edited the answer following your comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can add ***src*** to the ***python search path*** and then you can import *A* from *fileToImport.py*.
For this, you should write ***someFile.py*** like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")   # .. represente the father folder

from folderStrucutre1.fileToImport import A

instance_for_A = A()
```