# What is the appropriate way for a .py file to import another .py file in the same package,?

Tags: python, init, python-packaging, pythonpath

I have a folder `mypackage` at the location `/mypath/mypackage/`, and it contains an `__init__.py` file which is empty. mypackage contains two python files: `packagefile1` and `packagefile2`, and `packagefile2` contains `import packagefile1`.

When I then call a python script at `/myotherpath/script.py` which contains `import packagefile2`, it correctly finds `packagefile2`, but I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myotherpath/script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mypackage import packagefile2
  File "/mypath/packagefile2.py", line 16, in <module>
    import packagefile1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packagefile1'
```

However, I don't get this error when I call `packagefile2` directly, so it must be because I am not calling the scripts in the `mypackage` folder.

**What is the appropriate way to solve this?**

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory) that the solution is to change `import packagefile1` to `import .packagefile1`, but then I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398222/6399645) that relative imports using `.` are outdated. So what is the appropriate way to import modules within the same package?

ps: `/mypath/` is part of the pythonpath variable (when I command `env | grep -i python` in bash, it shows `PYTHONPATH=:/mypath/`).

Comment: This [link](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) may help you make some sense of how python imports work.

Comment: you should try this:
in the file "/mypath/packagefile2.py":

    from mypackage import packagefile1

Comment: @frippe, the link you sent clarified a lot, thank you :)