# Run a Python made CLI without running the .py file from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-interface, argparse

When you install Git on your computer, it can be run from the terminal with "git". Similarly, Python can be run with just "python" or "py".

If I make a CLI with argparse and Python, is there a way to have users simply install it and use it in the terminal just by typing

`$ myCLI -option`

Rather than

`$ python path\to\myCLI.py -option`

Like all the CLI's I use/interact with do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Crude Solution

Your script just needs to be somewhere in the user's `$PATH` (and to have no extension if you don't want them to type `myCLI.py`).  Additionally it needs to start with a magic comment `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (If you are running Linux) and be executable (on linux `chmod +x myCLI` prior to distributing it).  Alternatively you create a script in the native shell language of the desired OS (so `sh` for linux) which calls `python3 /path/to/script` or `python -m module` or the like.

If you you name your main script without a .py it prevents you importing it from anything else, so the usual approach is to have an 'entrypoint' script which consists of something like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from myApp import main
main()
```

(see [the PyPa docs](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/#use-for-scripts) for a discussion)

### Better solution

Of course, you need to deploy your entrypoint script somewhere in the end-user's `$PATH`.  This can be more intersting, but luckily the whole thing is handled by setuptools, and *you don't even need to write a script: you just need an entry point function*:

> Use console_script entry points to register your script interfaces. You can then let the toolchain handle the work of turning these interfaces into actual scripts

[official docs](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/?highlight=scripts#console-scripts)

you just put in your `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'PKG_NAME = package.module:func',
        ],
    }
)
```

and anyone who types `PKG_NAME` will effectively run `package.module:func()` (so `func` is your entrypoint `main()` function above).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787036/difference-between-entry-points-console-scripts-and-scripts-in-setup-py#28119736) for a discussion of the merits of this approach over the old approach of writing separate scripts for each platform.

Note that if you're not building your app as a python package, but are using some other packaging standard (archlinux PKGBUILD or .deb or whatever) you can still take the same approach---just write the entry point script as above and have the package place it somewhere in the user's `$PATH`.